# Is there a need to do any cleanup when using document.createElement within a React ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Per the title, if I were to do something like the code snippet below, since `React.useRef` will get called on every render, is there any need to do cleanup on the call to `document.createElement("div")`, or will the browser garbage collect that `div` that gets created when the next render comes?

I'm aware that if I were to actually append the `div` with `document.body.appendChild` then I'd need to clean up the element that actually gets appended...I'm just wondering about the `div` that's stored in memory after `React.useRef` is called.

```
function Modal() {
  const portalRef = React.useRef(document.createElement("div"));
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Since the div is appended directly to the document object it will be there while the document object exists or is rerendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DIV doesn't need to be cleaned up manually, but also the creation of the DIV doesn't relate to the fact that [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) is beeing called on every render, i.e. the DIV itself is created on every render, independently of useRef.

Consider this way of refactoring your code:

```
function Modal() {
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div"); // <-- new DIV created
  const portalRef = React.useRef( newDiv );     // <-- useRef called
  return null;
}
```

Here it becomes obvious how just a plain old DOM object (the new DIV) is created on every render. Normal Javascript / DOM behavior applies regarding the DIV.

`useRef` only uses the first created DIV as an initial value, and just ignores all following ones.

Indeed, this is a wasted creation of a DIV on every render. The best solution to this depends on the purpose of the code. E.g.:

- you should not use `document.createElement("div")` anyway,
- useRef would better only contain primitive values, instead of objects, and the DIV should be created by React mechanisms,
- when you need a constant, "expensive" initial value, you might create it only once, before the component is even mounted, outside of the component
- ... etc.

Furthermore, the value contained inside the `useRef` is also just a plain Javascript object (basically), and will behave as such.

I.e. `portalRef` is just an object `{ current: myInitialDiv }`, which lives as long as the component does, and gets deleted then.
Note that this `myInitialDiv` is still the first DIV that was created, not one of the later ones.